# Dependency injection with mockito example

Tags: spring, mockito

I am very new with Mockito and I don't get the following example (classes were provided, only test to write) and how to solve it.
What I try to do is use a test double for the supplier so that we can control the returned greeting in the test and assert that the GreetingService does not modify the greeting message in any way. Then assert that the returned greeting string is equal to "Hello Andy.".

```java
public class Greeting {
    private final String template;

    public Greeting(String template) {
        this.template = template;
    }

    public String forName(String world) {
        return String.format(template, world);
    }
}
```

```java
@Component
public class GreetingService {

    private final Supplier<Greeting> greetingSupplier;

    public GreetingService(Supplier<Greeting> greetingSupplier) {
        this.greetingSupplier = greetingSupplier;
    }

    public String greet(String name) {
        return greetingSupplier.get().forName(name);
    }
}
```

```java
@Component
public class RandomGreetingSupplier implements Supplier<Greeting> {

    private final List<Greeting> greetings = Arrays.asList(
            new Greeting("Hello %s."),
            new Greeting("Hi %s!"),
    );
    private final Random random = new Random();

    @Override
    public Greeting get() {
        return greetings.get(random.nextInt(greetings.size()));
    }
}
```

```java
@SpringBootTest
public class GreetingServiceTest {

    @Autowired
    GreetingService greetingService;

    @MockBean
    Supplier<Greeting> greetingSupplier;

    @Test
    void getGreetingForPerson() {
        String name = "Andy";
        // that test cannot know which greeting will be returned by the supplier
        // WHY IS IT NULLPOINTEREXCEPTION AFTER INITIALIZING @MockBean
        //String greeting = greetingService.greet(name); 
        //assertThat(greeting).contains(name);
        
        // WROTE SUCH TEST HERE -> NullPointerException WHY?
        Mockito.when(greetingSupplier.get().forName(name)).thenReturn("Hello %s.");
        assertThat(greetingSupplier.equals("Hello Andy."));
  
        // THIS IS WORKING & TEST PASSED BUT I GUESS ITS WRONG?
        Mockito.when(greetingSupplier.get()).thenReturn(new Greeting("Hello %s."));
        assertThat(greetingSupplier.equals("Hello Andy."));
   
    }
}
```

Comment: What you think is wrong is actually correct.

Comment: That excercise is wrong :). But as mentioned what you think is wrong is correct. You mocked `Supplier<Greeting>` and the default behavior is to return `null`. So when you call `greetingSupplier.get()` in your first line it returns `null`. You directly chain `forName` which nou basicall is `null.forName` which leads to an error.

Comment: Task of the exercise: Declare a new field of type Supplier<Greeting> in the class GreetingServiceTest.
Thank you so muc @M.Deinum

Answer (score 0):

`Mockito.when(greetingSupplier.get().forName(name)).thenReturn("Hello %s.");`

You can't chain calls like that, you need to produce intermediate results, like

```
Supplier<Greeting> supplier = mock(Supplier.class);
Mockito.when(supplier).forName().thenReturn("Hello %s.");
Mockito.when(greetingSupplier.get()).thenReturn(supplier);
```

For dependency injection, you need to create the subject under test with the mocked Supplier. You can do that in a `@Before` method for example.

Answer (score 0):

Your mocking is wrong.

```java
Mockito.when(greetingSupplier.get().forName(name)).thenReturn("Hello %s.");
```

You mocked `Supplier<Greeting>` and the default behavior is to return `null`. So when you call `greetingSupplier.get()` in your first line it returns `null`. You directly chain `forName` which nou basicall is `null.forName` which leads to an error.

Your second part is actually (kind of) correct.

```java
Mockito.when(greetingSupplier.get()).thenReturn(new Greeting("Hello %s."));
```

You now properly return a response from `greetingSupplier.get()`. Instead of chaining the call.

However I would argue that your excercise is wrong. Why? When using a `Supplier<?>` in Spring it actually is a lazy `beanFactory.getBean` call. You can lazily inject dependencies this way. You should have a mock for `Greeting` which returns a hardcoded `String` which you can check.